# Convert stange 3 byte HEX date format from DBF

Tags: date, hex, converters, dbf

I need to work with a DBF file (dBASE III PLUSE, with memo) which contains weirdly formatted date values. The values are saved as HEX numbers counting up for each day.

Now comes the weird part, the counter jumps (compare e.g. integer value) every month one and every year two values. Basically, it counts a 00 month and a 00 day.

**EDIT:** Further it counts for every month 31 days, e.g. end of February.

**EDIT 2:** Another strange implementation I didn't see before is, that each byte/hex value count's only until `7F` and then the next byte count's up e.g. `2001-02-15` -> `2001-02-16`...

```
HEX         Integer    Date       * not a valid date
====================================================
2E 22 30    3023408    1970-00-00 *
2E 22 31    3023409    1970-01-00 *
2E 22 32    3023410    1970-01-01
2E 22 33    3023411    1970-01-02
2E 22 34    3023412    1970-01-02
[...]
2E 22 50    3023440    1970-01-31
2E 22 51    3023441    1970-02-00 *
2E 22 52    3023442    1970-02-01
[...]
2E 22 6D    3023469    1970-02-28
2E 22 6E    3023470    1970-02-29 *
2E 22 6F    3023471    1970-02-30 *
2E 22 70    3023472    1970-02-31 *
2E 22 71    3023473    1970-03-00 *
2E 22 72    3023474    1970-03-01
[...]
2E 25 30    3024176    1970-12-31
2E 25 31    3024177    1971-00-00 *
2E 25 32    3024178    1971-01-00 *
2E 25 33    3024179    1971-01-01
[...]
2E 7F 7F    3047295    2001-02-15
2F 00 00    3080192    2001-02-16
[...]
```

With this knowledge, I could generate a list from 1900-01-01 until 2038-01-18, see [example.txt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wittich/3byte-hex-date/main/example.txt).

Is this a known pattern, I just never heard about it? 
Is there a simple way to convert date back and forward?

---

As [@js2010](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/125932171?noredirect=1) pointed out it's probably the 3 byte **Date of last update**, in `YYMMDD` format structure, see [dbase.com/Knowledgebase/INT/db7_file_fmt.htm](https://www.dbase.com/Knowledgebase/INT/db7_file_fmt.htm) . Though there isn't really a further explanation.

Comment: So the "date" field is a 6 Character field?  And no, I haven't seen that before.  I can see the beginning zero dates as "some time in this year/month, not exactly sure when"; maybe the ending zeros are for easier math.

Comment: Something doesn't add up here.  It appears that every month has 32 codes (for days 0...31) and the year has one extra 00-00 code.  That should result in 12*32+1 = 385 codes per year.  Since 1970 started with code (in decimal) 3023408, then 1971 should start at 3023408 + 385 = 3023793, but the table shows that 1971 actually starts at 3024177.  So, apparently, there are 769 codes per year, not 385, but the table shown doesn't seem to give any indication of what all of the extra codes are for.

Comment: Are you sure that 3024176 isn't actually 1971-12-31, and 3024177 isn't actually 1972-00-00, etc.?  It really looks like we skipped a year in there.

Comment: @AndrewMerrill I think, I finally understood it. One more fact I didn't understand before is each byte goes only to the hex value `7F` then it counts the next byte one up. So after 00 00 7F comes 00 01 00. I'll extend my question and provide an example list from 1900-01-01 until today.

Comment: It's not this?  YYMMDD https://www.dbase.com/Knowledgebase/INT/db7_file_fmt.htm

Comment: @js2010 you're right, it sounds like the 3 byte Date of last update, in YYMMDD format structure. I never heard about it before, and it took me a while to understand it. So far, I have only generated a [table](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wittich/3byte-hex-date/main/example.txt) to look for the value, but I didn't find a fast and easy convert.

Comment: Something like this comes out to 1972/05/01 `date "$(1900+0x48)/$(0x05)/$(0x01)"`